# Cosine similarity calculation issue

Tags: c#, cosine-similarity

I am having issues in calculation of cosine similarity between 2 strings.
I calculate the binary vector format of each string using a function. It gives out binary vectors which are in the form of, say, `(1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)`.

```
public static Tuple<int[],int[]> sentence_to_vector(String[] word_array1, String[] word_array2)
{
    String[] unique_word_array1 = word_array1.Distinct().ToArray();
    String[] unique_word_array2 = word_array2.Distinct().ToArray();
    String[] list_all_words = unique_word_array1.Concat(unique_word_array2).ToArray();
    String[] list_all_words_unique = list_all_words.Distinct().ToArray();

    int count_all_unique_words = list_all_words_unique.Length;
    int[] sentence1_vector = new int[count_all_unique_words];
    int[] sentence2_vector = new int[count_all_unique_words];

    for (int i = 0; i < count_all_unique_words; i++)
    {
        if (Array.IndexOf(unique_word_array1, list_all_words_unique[i]) >= 0)
        {
            sentence1_vector[i] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            sentence1_vector[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count_all_unique_words; i++)
    {
        if (Array.IndexOf(word_array2, list_all_words_unique[i]) >= 0)
        {
            sentence2_vector[i] = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            sentence2_vector[i] = 0;
        }
    } 

    return Tuple.Create(sentence1_vector, sentence2_vector);;

}
```

After I calculate the vector representation, I go for cosine similarity calculation.

The code is attached herewith:

```
public static float get_cosine_similarity(int[] sentence1_vector, int[] sentence2_vector)
{
    int vector_length = sentence1_vector.Length;
    int i = 0;
    float numerator = 0, denominator = 0;
    int temp1 = 0, temp2 = 0;
    double square_root1 = 0, square_root2 = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < vector_length; i++)
    {
        numerator += sentence1_vector[i] * sentence2_vector[i];
        temp1 += sentence1_vector[i] * sentence1_vector[i];
        temp2 += sentence2_vector[i] * sentence2_vector[i];
    }

    //TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("E://testpdf/date2.txt");
    square_root1 = Math.Sqrt(temp1);
    square_root2 = Math.Sqrt(temp2);
    denominator = (float)(square_root1 * square_root2);

    if (denominator != 0){
        return (float)(numerator / denominator);
        //return (float)(numerator);
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I checked out a site where in I can specify 2 strings and find the cosine similarity between them. The site is attached herewith:

http://cs.uef.fi/~zhao/Link/Similarity_strings.html

```
function implementationCosin(){
    var string1 = document.DPAform.str1.value;
    var s1 = stringBlankCheck(string1);

    var string2 = document.DPAform.str2.value;
    var s2 = stringBlankCheck(string2);

    if (s1.length < 1) {
        alert("Please input the string1.");
        return;
    }
    if (s2.length < 1) {
        alert("Please input the string2.");
        return;
    }

    document.DPAform.displayArea2.value = "";

    var sDT = new Date();
   // var begin = new Date().getTime();

    var cosin_similarity_value = consinSimilarity(s1, s2);
    document.DPAform.displayArea2.value += 'Cosin_Similarity(' + s1 + ',' + s2 + ')=' + cosin_similarity_value + '%\n';

    var eDT = new Date();
      var timediff = sDT.dateDiff("ms", eDT);
   // var timediff = (new Date().getTime() - begin);

    document.DPAform.displayArea2.value += "The total escaped time is: " + timediff + " (ms).\n";
}
```

Even if 2 sentences are 0% similar, my codes says that there is some amount of similarity between them.

Comment: Please remove the code which is not needed to reproduce the issue, e.g. code in comments.

Comment: Debug and narrow down which part does not behave as you expect... Consider updating your post with just `GetCosineSimilarity` function and hardcoded input values that show case where you expect 0 but got something else.

Comment: @Biju Did you try converting the exact consinSimilarity(...) function from the website you gave? If I convert the code to C# I could see results similar to the website. Or you want to take different approach than the website uses?

Comment: @ Alexei Levenkov and @Siva Gopal, I have found out the error using debugging. I have used hardcoded inputs as instructed and has traced out the bug. Thanks both of you. :-)